# PHP Regex throwing error messages

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I have looked at the documentation that PHP provides on [PCRE Patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).  I am using a third party plugin to handle some text from the user, and the following preg_replace is failing because of missing terminating ] char.  (preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class

```
$input  = preg_replace('/[\]/i','',$userInput);
```

From what I can see the terminating delimiter is / with a character class that only has a \ in it.  The i, if I can read correctly tells the expression to not care about upper or lower case.  I see both opening [ and closing ].

Why is it throwing the error?   What is the preg_replace trying to do?

Comment: To match a backslash use `\\\\ ` !

Comment: @Ham: \\\ is what you want.

Comment: @webbiedave Ah yes, that will also work :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` otherwise it escapes the `]` (and you need to escape it twice, once for the PHP string and once for PCRE).

```
$input  = preg_replace('/[\\\]/i','',$userInput);
```

And you can omit the `[` and `]` altogether (as well as the `i`).

```
$input  = preg_replace('/\\\/','',$userInput);
```

Or, you can just use `str_replace`:

```
$input  = str_replace('\\','',$userInput);
```

Comment: So you are telling me that whole thing was to replace \\ with blanks.  I don't know why the script would do that, but re-write it I shall.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming it's a very poor attempt at escaping for an SQL query, but not know what library you're using I can only speculate.

Comment: As a rule it is better to use four backslashes to match a backslash in PHP. Although it does not apply in this case, if another backslashed character was following the three backslashes, the pattern may not be interpreted as intended.